# Is there a way to redirect from one plugin to another plugin in Extbase?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

Using Typo3 V11.5.15
I need a way to move from a form, where you add a new employee to a list, to another form when the given company doesn't exist yet.

I tried using redirect and the URI builder but nothing seems to work.

I do explicitly **NOT** want to have a f:link.action in a second page where the user can check the input. I often see this recommended in older threads.

---

**Edit1**
I did check into the 4 year old work around for the old bug with redirect using AJAX. But this should be obsolete by now and the older solutions seem to not work.

---

**Edit2**

I did something similar to Stefan Bürk's answer suggests.

```php
//added the UriBuilder first
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder;

//new instance of UriBuilder and using it to ... build the Uri....
$uriBuilder = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(UriBuilder::class);
$uriBuilder->setTargetPageUid($PageUidGoesHere);
$uri = $uriBuilder->uriFor($ControllerAction, $ParametersArray, $ControllerName, $ExtensionName, $PluginName);
//redirecting to selfmade Uri
return $this->redirectToUri($uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to mention the used TYPO3 core version. In some of the newer core versions, where extbase is request/response aware, returning a redirect response in the extbase controller action may not work. If this is the case for you, you should be able to create a redirect response and throw it as a PropagateResponseException, which leaves some places out and jumpts to an outer place in the request onion - and thus returning a proper redirect to the browser.

```php
// build your uri with uri builder 
$redirectUri = $this->uriBuilder->uriFor(....);
$redirectResponse = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\RedirectResponse($redirectUri, 307, []);
throw new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\PropagateResponseException($redirectResponse, 0);
```

You may also use the $this->redirect(..) or $this->rediretToUri() method to create the $redirectResponse and throw it then.

```php
throw new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\PropagateResponseException(
  $this->redirect(....), 0);
```

Comment: I was about to comment how I just did it on my own. I did use the UriBuilder to be able to add a plugin I want to redirect to and then used the actioncontroller's redirectToUri method to go where I want to go. I think it's pretty annoying there is no possibility in the action controllers's redirect method to add a plugin.
Thanks for your answer. Hope this helps other people struggling.